# Parameter type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, oop

I am a very beginner programmer, i have a headache for whole day.

The code below has error "Parameter type is less accessible than method" on line :
"        public static int NewUserEvent(UserEventInput input)"

```
public partial class GameWebService : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

   [WebMethod]
    public static int NewUserEvent(UserEventInput input)
    {
        return input.eventid;
    }


}
public class UserEventInput
{

    public string memberid { get; set; }
    public int eventid { get; set; }
    public int topicid { get; set; }
    public int levelid { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Nope, seems ok to me. Is it possible that you have _another_ UserEventInput class somewhere?

Comment: To find out the above - Right click on `UserEventInput` in your parameter and click go to definition

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: you should write that up as an answer, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I'm not the OP.  His answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Benjamin and Sayse,
I am totally a stupid. You are right.
The fact is , the parameter class code, it was cut from another .cs file and paste here.
But I have not save that another .cs file to disk.......so there are 2 class with same name in under the same namespace.....what a fool i am.